# Nested backquote in find command on Linux

Tags: linux, find

```
find `find `ls .` -user ${USER}` -maxdepth 0 -perm /g+w
```

The command is not working as expected.

Comment: See [Why is `$(...)` preferred over \`...\` (backticks)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

`find` accepts multiple tests. No need to nest calls.

```
find . -user "$USER" -perm /g+w
```